# Adding image to input type submit

Tags: html, css

I have a button with an SVG image. I have successfully added the image for `div`'s, but unsure on how to apply it to input tags.

For example:

```css
.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

i.arrow {
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/Arrow.svg);
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 4px 0 4px 10px;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}


/***********/

input {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 28px 0 1em;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px 1.2em;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  border: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
  /*background: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/Arrow.svg) no-repeat scroll 14px 7px;
    background-size: 20px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="formLink">Download now <i class="arrow"></i></div><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="hs-button primary large" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.4.1.0">
```

As you can see, I've tried to add `background:url` to the input, but it hide's my whole button?

I essentially want the send message button to look like the download now button.

Ideas? **I cannot change the input HTML. Need to do this through CSS**

Comment: Are you looking for input type image? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image

Comment: make it as a button with an action triggered on click? OR wrap in `<a>` tags

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot the clarify, I cannot change the input HTML. Need to do this through CSS.

Comment: I opened the image and saw it(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/Arrow.svg). Its nothing other than plain white background. If you really have some image with picture, you can give `background-size: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/328055/

```
<div class="formLink">Download now <i class="arrow"></i></div><br>
<button type="submit" value="Send Message" class="hs-button primary large formLink" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.4.1.0"> Send Message<i class="arrow"></i></button>
```

Comment: This works, but please also add a little detail about why in OP's original HTML code it didn't work.

Comment: we can't put images over input button directly, we have to use either with a <button> || anchor <a> tag || <span> tag with some CSS

Comment: Hi Joseph, I can see it works, but unfortunately I cannot alter the HTML markup. Therefore I cannot change input into a button. Any way to do this via CSS for input?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.formLink {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 88px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
  padding: 24px 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

i.arrow {
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/Arrow.svg);
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 4px 0 4px 10px;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}


/***********/
i.new {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/548247/Tomorrow%20People/Landing%20Page/Template%20Build/Arrow.svg);
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 53px 15px 19px 179px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
   
}

input.hs-button.primary.large.formLink {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px 0 1em;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px 40px;
    width: 220px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'GeomanistRegular', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
    border: 0;
    transition: all .6s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="formLink">Download now <i class="arrow"></i></div><br>
     <input type="submit"  value="Send Message" class="hs-button primary large formLink" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.4.1.0"><i class="new"></i></input>
```